# java swt jface TreeViewer expanding from node

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I expand the node to its root node?

So I have this method to expand its parent node recursively

```
private void expand( Object object ) {
    if ( object.getParent() != null ) {
        tree.setExpandedState( object.getParent(), true );
        expand( object.getParent() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `expandToLevel` `TreeViewer` method:

```
viewer.expandToLevel(element, 1);
```

`element` can be your model element (the object your content provider provides) or it can be a `TreePath`. You may need to call `setUseHashlookup(true)` on the viewer to speed up element lookup.